# std::copy two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello I'm trying to use the std::copy() function to copy a two dimensional array.  I was wondering if it's possible to do it like so!  I keep getting a "Segmentation Fault" but the array is copied correctly.  I've tried subtracting a few and adding a few to the end case for the copy function, but with no success.

```
    const int rows = 3;
    const int columns = 3;
    int myint[rows][columns]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int favint[rows][columns];
    std::copy(myint, myint+rows*columns,favint);
```

It's obvious that "myint+rows*columns" is incorrect, and it turns out that this value corresponds to entire rows such that "myint+rows*columns=1" means it will copy the entire first row.  if "myint+rows*columns=2" it copies the first two rows etc.  Can someone explain the operation of this for me?

Comment: This piece of code runs perfectly fine on my machine. Are you sure it is this part of your code that is causing the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
std::copy(myint, myint+rows*columns,favint);
```

should be:

```
std::copy(&myint[0][0], &myint[0][0]+rows*columns,&favint[0][0]);
```

prototype of `std::copy`:

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
```

Notice that pointer to array element could be wrapper as an iterator.

Comment: @Mahesh The difference is myint is pointer of pointer to myint[0][0] , &myint[0][0] is pointer to myint[0][0]. Big difference.

Comment: @lulyon They are the same. A 2-d array is resolved into a pointer pointing to the very first element too.

Comment: @texasbruce No. A 2-d array is resolved into a pointer pointing to the very first **1-d array that begin with the first element**.

Comment: @lulyon `cout << myint << endl;
    cout << &myint[0][0] << endl;` and output: `0x7fffdb8969b0
0x7fffdb8969b0`

Comment: @texasbruce `myint` is itself not a pointer; it is converted to a pointer after passing to a function(or assigned to a pointer).

Comment: @texasbruce I too was thinking the same. It has nothing to do with the address but the type of the `myint` when passed as `myint` and `&myint[0][0]` that differs.

Comment: @Mahesh My first comment made a mistake that "myint is pointer of pointer to myint[0][0]". No, myint is pointer of pointer to myint[0][0] only after converted to a pointer.

Comment: @Mahesh I see what u mean. The addresses are the same. Its just the function cannot resolve the type. Strange it is working on my machine with no issue