# Why can't I use std::copy in my copy constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

I'm writing a class that encapsulates a 2-dimensional array. This is the copy constructor. (`WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are compile-time constants, which is why I saw it fit to use arrays.)

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &other)
{
    std::copy(
            &array[0][0], &array[0][0] + WIDTH*HEIGHT,
            &other.array[0][0]);
}
```

I'm using a method that is correct according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709577/stdcopy-two-dimensional-array), and worked before I changed the prototype to be `const &` rather than simple pass-by-value. However, I now receive this compiler error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:40,
                 from MyClass.hpp:4,
                 from MyClass.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = ArrayDataType*; _OI = const ArrayDataType*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:428:38:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = ArrayDataType*; _OI = const ArrayDataType*]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:460:17:   required from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = ArrayDataType*; _OI = const ArrayDataType*]’
MyClass.cpp:17:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:390:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__copy_move<false, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(ArrayDataType*&, ArrayDataType*&, const ArrayDataType*&)’
                        _Category>::__copy_m(__first, __last, __result);
                                                                      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:390:70: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:368:9: note: template<class _Tp> static _Tp* std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(const _Tp*, const _Tp*, _Tp*) [with _Tp = _Tp; bool _IsMove = false]
         __copy_m(const _Tp* __first, const _Tp* __last, _Tp* __result)
         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:368:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:390:70: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_Tp’ (‘ArrayDataType’ and ‘const ArrayDataType’)
                        _Category>::__copy_m(__first, __last, __result);
```

I'd assume that the C++ standard wouldn't make `std::copy` unusable in a copy constructor by constant reference in this fashion, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `std::copy` has trouble with multidimensional arrays, but you haven't provided their definitions to us. If your copy constructor just performs a copy of each element, then you don't need to provide it. The compiler generates one automatically.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::array`?

Comment: The way you've written it, isn't it trying to copy `array` to `other.array` instead of the other way around?

Comment: I agree it looks like you're trying to copy `this` TO `other` instead of from.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah. That's the problem. *Sigh.* I hate to be "that guy" who spams Stack Overflow with syntax errors, but it always ends up that way. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This log

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘_OI
>   std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II =
>   ArrayDataType*; _OI = **const** ArrayDataType*]’:

and following few lines are interesting. Error log points to the `__result` which is an alias to the third parameter passed by you.

This is generated from the following lines of code.

```
std::copy(
        &array[0][0], &array[0][0] + WIDTH*HEIGHT,
        &other.array[0][0]);
```

Copy is declared as:

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
```

You are trying to copy `array` to `other.array` and the destination is `const`.

You can change the syntax to:

```
std::copy(
        &other.array[0][0], &other.array[0][0] + WIDTH*HEIGHT,
        &array[0][0]);
```

But I would recommend to use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of `std::array` to write a less confusing syntax as:

```
array = other.array;
```

---

This confusion came from some language design decisions:

Assignation operator is used as:

```
LHS = RHS;
```

Now to preserve the same order, `C` defined its functions as:

```
strcpy(LHSstring, RHSstring);  /* LHSstring = RHSstring; Similar in memcpy etc */
```

But `C++` STL design is different and has following construct:

```
SOME_FUNC(from_iterator, to_iterator, something...);
/* foreach, transform, sort etc */
```

So the following (though confusing) are analogous

```
memcpy(dest, src, len * sizeof dest[0]);
std::copy(src, src + len, dst);
```